# Laravel after clearing cache redirect doesnt work

Tags: laravel, redirect, caching, config

I noticed that during the development of my Laravel app the `return redirect()` sometimes doesnt work when I try to register or login into my app. I hit the submit button and the page just keeps loading and I can see that chrome says "processing" and keeps spinning, so I have to manually click the browser refresh button in order to get redirected to the account page meaning that the user successfully logged in or registered.

But sometimes it works just fine which is strange.

So today I tried to clear the Laravel cache and browser cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```

And do a "empty cache and hard reload" on chrome

After that I tried to register a user, and this time redirect didnt work again.

So I checked telescope to look at the headers and noticed this:

The times redirect doesnt work I can see:

```
referer: "https://www.mysite.test/login",
origin: "https://www.mysite.test",
host: "www.mysite.test"
```

And the times when redirect works the headers looks like this:

```
referer: "https://mysite.test/login",
origin: "https://mysite.test",
host: "mysite.test"
```

So why is "www" added to the url when I clear the cache and why does adding "www" keeps `redirect()` from working?

I am running my app through Valet if that matters

**Edit**
I also noticed if I login into "https://example.com" then visit "https://www.example.com" I am not logged in under that domain since the cookie doesnt seem to be set for both "www" and without "www"

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seemed the problem was that I had to change domain => '.example.com' in my settings, sometimes the app redirected me between www and without www. And the session was not set over the entire domain